# How do I execute a linux shell script from within an existing apk?

Tags: android, shell, package, apk

Where, inside an apk - say one that's already written, and is decompiled via apkeditor - do I insert a shell script to launch it (I.e. using an existing link in an apk to fire a shell script {pm enable [packagename] } )?

This ia what was given in another post:

```
{
    proc = runtime.exec("Is_This_Where_It_Goes?");
    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
    osw.write(command);
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();
}
```

Or somewhere else?

I'm looking to do a ' pm enable ' in a [de/re]compiled app, and this is probably the easiest method.

Thanks!

Nothing has been tried, since no location I could fathom worked. :(

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't think apps have permission to run `pm disable`.  See, e.g., [How to hide other apps in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36362056/208273)

Comment: No, apps generally don't, but I CAN run ' su -c ' passing the command over for permissions... I actually meant 'pm enable'. Sorry.

Comment: Oh, you have root.  I'll link a relevant question, then.